# Cannot get cron going in WordPress using wp-cli

Tags: wordpress, cron

I’m trying to get cron going using wp-cli

WordPress: 6.0.3
civiCRM: 5.52.0
PHP: 7.4.32

I think I found the path to wp-cli.

$ wp —info yields:
WP_CLI phar path:   /home/customer/www/mywebsite.org/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm

But executing wp throws a syntax error at the path:

$ wp --user=MyName --url=https://mywebsite.org —-path=home/customer/www/mywebsite.org/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm api job.execute auth=0

Error: '—-path=home/customer/www/mywebsite.org/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm' is not a registered wp command. See 'wp help' for available commands.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Seems a bit strange to me that you've got WP-CLI installed in the CiviCRM plugin directory. I'd suggest moving it somewhere outside your `public_html` directory.

When you've done that and got it working, try this for cron:

```
wp --user=MyName --url=https://mywebsite.org --path=/home/customer/www/mywebsite.org/public_html civicrm api job.execute auth=0
```

The `--path` is the path to the WordPress directory rather than the path to the CiviCRM plugin directory. Plus I think you have something other than `--path` there.